# Python - urllib3 MaxRetryError when trying to log in to a website using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I searched for similar questions on this forum but there wasn't much help. If someone can point me to the help or if this question is a duplicate, I will close or edit it.

Scenario:
I am trying to automate the login process for a website. The code sometimes works fine, logs in and closes the browser. But there are a few errors caused by urllib3 MaxRetry and Connection refusal that lead to the browser window getting closed in the middle of a test. I tried to use time.sleep but that didn't help.

Here is the code, the error and the stack trace.

```
import sys
import argparse
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
import urllib3
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry
import time


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('browser', default='chrome', help='Types of browser:chrome, firefox, ie')
parser.add_argument('username', help='This is the  username')
parser.add_argument('password', help='This is the  password')
args = parser.parse_args()

setup_parameters = sys.argv[1:]


class Browser(object):
    """The Login class contains methods to log in to the Premier portal
       with the supplied browser, username and password as command line arguments.
       The webdriver then waits for the number of seconds specified in the implicit wait method
       and finally the quit method closes the browser.
     """
    url = 'https:someurl.com'

# Initialization Method
    def __init__(self):
        self.username = setup_parameters[1]
        self.password = setup_parameters[2]
        if setup_parameters[0] == 'chrome':
            self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()
            print("Running tests on Chrome browser")
            self.browser.implicitly_wait(15)
            self.site_login()
            self.site_close()
        elif setup_parameters[0] == 'ie':
            self.browser = webdriver.Ie()
            print("Running tests on Internet Explorer browser")
            self.browser.implicitly_wait(15)
            self.site_login()
            self.site_close()
        elif setup_parameters[0] == 'firefox':
            self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
            print("Running tests on Firefox browser")
            self.browser.implicitly_wait(15)
            self.site_login()
            self.site_close()
        elif setup_parameters[0] == 'None':
            print('No browser type specified.... continuing with the default browser')
            self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()


# Method used to log in to the site
    def site_login(self):
        try:
            self.browser.get(self.url)
            self.browser.find_element_by_id("Username").send_keys(self.username)
            self.browser.find_element_by_id("Password").send_keys(self.password)
            self.browser.find_element_by_id("btnLogin").click()
            time.sleep(30)
        except requests.ConnectionError as e:
            print("******Connection error encountered! Trying again....")
            print(str(e))
            time.sleep(10)
        except requests.Timeout as e:
            print("*****Timeout Error!********")
            print(str(e))
        except requests.RequestException as e:
            time.sleep(30)
            print("*******Server rejected the requests, too many requests!*******")
            print(str(e))
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("*********User interruption detected*******")
        except ConnectionRefusedError as e:
            time.sleep(30)
            print(str(e))
            print("*********Portal Connection refused by the server**********")
        except urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError as e:
            print(str(e))
            print("********Portal New connection timed out***********")
            time.sleep(30)
        except urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError as e:
            print(str(e))
            time.sleep(30)
            print("*********Portal Max tries exceeded************")
        except urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError as e:
            time.sleep(10)
            print("**********Timeout error************")
        except urllib3.exceptions.ClosedPoolError as e:
            time.sleep(10)
            print(str(e))
        except urllib3.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
            time.sleep(10)
            print(str(e))



        self.browser.maximize_window()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(10)

# Closing the browser window and terminating the test
    def site_close(self):
        self.browser.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    Browser().site_login()
    Browser().site_close()







C:\PycharmProjects\PortalAutomation>python Login.py ie 1EADMIN password1

Running tests on Internet Explorer browser

HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=62084): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/628678c3-b918-461a-bf41-0deaf16f4317/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTT
PConnection object at 0x00000000039C9908>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))

*********Portal Max tries exceeded************

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 79, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 69, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 956, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 196, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 180, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000000039C9FD0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be ma
de because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Login.py", line 110, in <module>
    Browser().site_login()
  File "Login.py", line 100, in site_login
    self.browser.maximize_window()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 736, in maximize_window
    self.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 318, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 375, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 402, in _request
    resp = http.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 72, in request
    **urlopen_kw)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 150, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 322, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=62084): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/628678c3-b918-461a-bf41-0deaf16f4317/window/maximize (Caused
by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000000039C9FD0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the t
arget machine actively refused it'))
```

Comment: Can anyone help me with this? The session isn't up and web page closes after the retries are exhausted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my own script. I was calling the method site_login and site_close in my script which was causing this issue.

I was calling the site_login and site_close methods in my *init* method.

Thanks everyone.